# Stop Following a SocialActor doesn't work when the site doesn't exist

Tags: 2013, social, community, following

One of my users can't stop following one specific site. It appears on the `.GetFollowed()` array, but the site doesn't exist anymore, so when `.StopFollowing()` it says `False` and log says that `Exception: ItemDoesNotExist : Item does not exist`. On it's own way I suppose makes sense: the site doesn't exist anymore, but in the other hand only a URL is needed for doing this, and I can remove other non-existing sites without any issue.

If I create a site with the same name and URL again and start following it, both appear at the followed items array but, of course, with different ID. If I stop following it, only the last one gets removed ignoring the non-existing one no matter what.

Even after specifying the ID with

```
$socialActor = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialActorInfo
$socialActor.Id = $ID
$socialActor.ContentUri = $URL
$socialActor.ActorType = [Microsoft.Office.Server.Social.SPSocialActorType]::Site
$followingManager.stopfollowing($socialActor)
```

only the last one is removed, even though their IDs don't match.

Recovering the site from backups, so I can be sure that the exact same site exists, is not an option because it was deleted several months ago.

Is there any workaround to achieve this? SharePoint bug, perhaps?

EDIT: Moreover,

`$spProfile.FollowedContent.GetItem($URL)`
returns null
`$spProfile.FollowedContent.IsFollowed($URL)`returns false
`$spProfile.FollowedContent.GetItem($anotherWorkingURL)` returns its details
`$spProfile.FollowedContent.IsFollowed($anotherWorkingURL)`returns true

while both appear at

`$spProfile.FollowedContent.GetItems([Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.FollowedContentQueryOptions]::All, 1)`

I've disassembled the .dll for checking how both `GetItem` and `GetItems` work trying to find some bug on the former, without success. But I´m sure there must be one around...

EDIT: I've managed to restore the original site, with the same ID it had when it was deleted, and everything is the same.